# Modal(popup) should be a Component or Directive in Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I need to create a Modal(Popup) which can called from any other component.
I have confusion here that it should be **Component** or **Directive**.

One more thing how to send event to Modal Component from other component. In my understanding it should be sent through Service.

Please Suggest

Comment: please consider accepting my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is of course subjective. But, components are directives with templates, so if your modal is going to have a template, it should be implemented as a component. This is the first rationale. The second one is that directives are usually used to alter/modify behavior, not create completely new.

> One more thing how to send event to Modal Component from other
>   component. In my understanding it should be sent through Service.

Yes, I would create a service that will be shared between all components that want to communicate with the modal.